# Best way to get line numbers in text area in firefox

Tags: firefox

I am interested if it is possible (via plugin or other means) to add line numbers (and perhaps more) to vanilla firefox text areas (I know there are various code editors, and there is its all text plug in, but wasn't sure if there was something simpler that works in place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[try this](http://4umi.com/web/javascript/textarea.php)